# How do I find data from arr in user object

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I need to set the array arr to the variable data on server side method in while loop. I have tried `var data = meteor.user().arr;` and `this.user.arr`. Here is the user object structure.

```
Accounts.createUser({
   username: username,
   password: password,
   email: email,
   arr:[],
   profile: {,
      bio: bio
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example which extracts `arr` from within a method. Note the correct capitalization of `Meteor`.

```js
Meteor.methods({
  something: function () {
    var user = Meteor.user();
    var arr = user && user.arr;
    console.log(arr);
  }
});
```

Comment: My bad I should have said server side not client for where i'm calling it.

Comment: Oh I see. In what context are you trying to use it (method, publish function, etc.)?

Comment: method in a while loop

Comment: See if the updated answer helps. If not, I can't help more without seeing the method.

Comment: [new version of the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821511/why-is-the-arr-array-not-in-the-users-object-after-creation-of-it)