# Why is the arr array not in the users object after creation of it?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am try to make arr a array that every user has but is never sent to client side. A day ago the it stopped being put into user objects on user create. Here is the code; thanks.

client

```
Template.create_user.events({
 'click #create-user-button': function() {
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var bio = $("#bio").val() || "";
    if (!username || !password || !email) {
    } else {
      Accounts.createUser({
        username: username,
        password: password,
        email: email,
        arr:[],
        profile: {
            bio: bio
        }
      });

     }  
   }
 });
```

server/user.js

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  if (options.profile)
    user.profile = options.profile;
  return user;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Accounts.createUser](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser) takes an object with **at most 4 fields**: username, email, password, and profile. You are passing in `arr`, which is being ignored by the server. You have two options:

1. Put `arr` inside of the `profile` object.
2. Add `arr` to the user in the `Accounts.onCreateUser` callback.

### option 1:

```js
Accounts.createUser({
  username: username,
  password: password,
  email: email,
  profile: {
      bio: bio,
      arr: []
  }
});
```

### option 2:

```js
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  if (options.profile)
    user.profile = options.profile;
  user.arr = [];
  return user;
});
```

In that case, you will also need to publish the extra field so that the client can see it. See the [users](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users) section of the docs. Specifically:

```js
// server
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, {fields: {arr: 1}});
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});

// client
Meteor.subscribe("userData");
```

Comment: These APIs have not changed in a long time, so I don't have much to offer beyond wild speculation. :)